# Python print command is not giving any output in command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
python -c 'print("hi sury")';
```

I typed this command in command prompt, but I got nothing as output on STDOUT. How to resolve this error?

Comment: Cannot replicate. Do you have Python installed? Any error messages?

Comment: Cannot duplicate.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Works for me with both python2 and python3

Comment: type `which python` and `which python3` and post the output here

Comment: What OS? On Windows, I found I needed to do `python -c "print('hi sury')"`.

Comment: Yes. I have python installed. There is no error message. Just a blank output. And also which command is giving this error.''which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.' I'm using windows10. Python version is python 3.6.1